# What does F^n notation represent conceptually?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am currently studying linear algebra and have come across this notation in my textbook

> let  be an ordered basis for $F^n$

Could someone explain more conceptually what the term $F^n$ represents? I am well familiar with vectors. When I see $F$ I think of fields which to me is just a set of scalar values. What does it mean to have a $n$ scalar values as represented in $F^n$. Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: $F^n$ is the vector space of ordered $n$-tuples of the field, i.e.$$F^n = \{(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) : x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n \in F\}.$$Addition and scalar multiplication are defined componentwise. It's analogous to $\Bbb{R}^n$ or $\Bbb{C}^n$, just more general (and I don't know how anyone could study linear algebra without seeing $\Bbb{R}^n$ at least!).

Comment: Note that $Y^X$ denotes the set of functions from $X$ to $Y$. So one (usually does not, but formally it is what happens) may identify a vector in $F^n$ with a function from $[n]$ to $F$